# Regex R separate punctuation from text preserving "e.g." and "i.e."

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I want to separate punctuation from text in R (prior to tokenization based on space).

Command: `gsub("(?:\b| )?([.,:;!?]+)(?: |\b)?", " \\1 ", "Blabla, i.e. blabla...")`

Output: `"Blabla , i . e . blabla ... "`

As you can see `...` is considered a single unit and is not broken down. How to achieve the same thing for `i.e` (and `e.g.`)?

To make it clear, the desired output is: `"Blabla , i.e. blabla ... "`

Comment: It does not seem feasible without a list of exceptions *unless* there is some specific restriction you have. Like `l.l.` where `l` is a letter should be excluded from a match. Consider `gsub("\\b\\pL\\.(?:\\pL\\.)+(*SKIP)(*F)|(\\.{3}|\\pP+)", " \\1", s, perl=T)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think a list of exceptions would work for me, since I am really only interested in those two specific cases (`e.g.` and `i.e.`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only interested in `i.e.` and `e.g.` as exceptions, you can put them in a list to skip, and match all other punctuation:

```
gsub("\\b(?:e\\.g\\.|i\\.e\\.)(*SKIP)(*F)|(\\pP+)", " \\1 ", 
  "Blabla, i.e. e.g. blabla...",
     perl=T)
## => [1] "Blabla ,  i.e. e.g. blabla ... "
```

See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/BMcmK1) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQ3dM2/1)

*Explanation*:

- `\\b(?:e\\.g\\.|i\\.e\\.)(*SKIP)(*F)` - match whole words `e.g.` or `i.e.` and skip them
- `|` - or
- `(\\pP+)` - match and capture into Group 1 one or more punctuation symbols

To keep the trimming in place, use

```
gsub("\\b(?:e\\.g\\.|i\\.e\\.)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:\\b|\\h+)?(\\pP+)(?:\\b|\\h+)?", " \\1 ", 
  "Blabla, i.e. e.g. blabla...",
     perl=T)
```

[Another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQ3dM2/2)

Comment: many thanks, could you please show me how to add the list of exceptions to the exact regex I provided in my question?

Comment: would it be `gsub("\\b(?:e\\.g\\.|i\\.e\\.)(*SKIP)(*F)|((?:\b| )?([.,:;!?]+)(?: |\b)?)", " \\1 ", "Blabla,,, i.e. e.g. blabla...", perl=T)`? But I think what you proposed is actually doing the same thing in a more compact way...

Comment: would it mean that I can replace the whole `(?:\b| )?([.,:;!?]+)(?: |\b)?` thing by `\\pP+`?

Comment: `[.,:;!?]+` is a subpart of `\pP+`. The `(?:\b| )?` are for trimming (I now recall your previous question). Turn it into `(?:\\b|\\h+)?` and add to the matching part on both sides. See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Cyzy3j).

Comment: Note that `\h+` matches 1 or more *horizontal* whitespace in a PCRE regex. This way, you will even match hard/non-breaking spaces.